# Call a method after finishing audio

Tags: ios, audio, loops, methods, call

I am new in IOS development. I have a method which will play an audio and the method is inside a loop. So i want to delay the method and check while playing audio is finished or not.

The code look like this

```
 for (int i=0; i<arrcount; i++) {

  [self performSelector:@selector(partsbuttonclicked:) withObject:[pArr objectAtIndex:0] afterDelay:0];


     [pArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
 }
```

Comment: Why not just play the next sound when the previous one is finished instead of check if you are still playing? How do you play the sound?

Comment: I am playing sound using AVAudioPlayerDelegate and there is a delegate method called audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying but i am having trouble to check the audioplayer did finish playing or not inside the loop.

Comment: You don't need to loop, just load the next sound in the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`